# Error loading psycopg2 module on OS Big Sur i.c.w. Apple Silicon

Tags: django, postgresql, psycopg2, macos-big-sur

Try to install a Django Project on my new Apple Silicon machine with OS 11/Big Sur.
When I try to run a manage.py command I get the following error:

```
/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 29, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: dlopen({removed}/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PQbackendPID
  Referenced from: {removed}/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

I have postgres installed with the Postgres.app

Tried al kind go things. f.i.
setting up the following symlink in /usr/local/lib

```
libpq.5.dylib -> /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/lib/libpq.5.13.dylib
```

Installing the psycopg2-binary gave me other errors.

So far, no luck. Not sure if the cause is OS11 or the new Silicon.

Answer (score 0):

I also experience the same thing as yours. Using default Terminal or even using Visual Studio Code Terminal routing to zsh will also failed.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dK8w.png

I finally can do `python manage.py runserver` using iTerm but running with Rosetta.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3mlU.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kfWU.png